# How to set a symbolic breakpoint on only some overrides?

Tags: xcode, debugging, swift, breakpoints, lldb

Consider the following code:

```
class Parent {
    func breakMethod() {
        println("p break")
    }
    func breakMethod(#variable: Int) {
        println("p breakpoint " + String(variable))
    }
}

class Child: Parent {
    override func breakMethod() {
        println("c break")
    }
    override func breakMethod(#variable: Int) {
        println("c breakpoint " + String(variable))
    }
}

let p = Parent()
let c = Child()

p.breakMethod()
c.breakMethod()
p.breakMethod(variable:0)
c.breakMethod(variable:1)
```

And obviously, realistically, this could and would be much more complex.  Suppose I need to debug one of these methods in every class which implements it.  One option is to go through every file and find every instance of `breakMethod` and manually add a breakpoint.  But the far better option is to add a symbolic breakpoint to `breakMethod`.

Xcode will then take care of adding the break point in every appropriate location.  I can then manually pick and choose which breakpoints I want and disable some of appropriate.  But more importantly, with a single click, I can enable/disable all of them for this specific symbol.  This is convenient.

But what if I want to add a breakpoint for `breakMethod(#variable: Int)`?  Can this be done?

I know, obviously, that I can set it for `breakMethod`.  That will catch every override of `breakMethod`.  And then I can go just enable only the ones I want.  But this becomes a major pain in any scenario much more complex than this.

In Objective-C, we'd actually have separate method that look something like this:

```
- (void)breakMethod {
    NSLog("break");
}

- (void)breakMethodVariable:(int)variable {
    NSLog("break %i", variable);
}
```

In which case, adding a symbolic breakpoint for "breakMethod" will only stop on the first method, and we can add a separate symbolic breakpoint for "breakMethodVariable:" that will only stop on the second method.

But no matter what I do, I can't seem to segregate the method overrides when setting symbolic breakpoints for Swift.  Is there something I'm missing?

For what it's worth, I've tried setting up the following symbolic breakpoints, none of them have worked for me:

- `breakMethod(variable:)`
- `breakMethod(variable)`
- `breakMethod(#variable:)`
- `breakMethod(Variable:)`
- `breakMethod(Variable)`
- `breakMethod(#Variable:)`
- `breakMethodvariable:`
- `breakMethodVariable:`
- `breakMethodvariable`
- `breakMethodVariable`
- `breakMethodWithVariable:`
- `breakMethodWithVariable`
- `breakMethodWithvariable:`
- `breakMethodWithvariable`

I'd be extremely disappointing to know there is no way to set separate symbolic breakpoints in Swift, considering what user to be a plethora of different methods in Objective-C has, in many cases, turned into a complex set of overrides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how to do it in Xcode Breakpoint navigator, and make them persist across execution.

But, as a workaround, you can use regex break point for that:

```
(lldb) breakpoint set -r "\.breakMethod \(.+\(variable :"
```